Selfhosted WCF (windows service) over HTTPS
I have a WCF Service self-hosted on a Windows Service. Currenlty its running over http, but i need to change it to https. I've made some changes on the .config file. The service starts, but seems not to be listening on any on the endpoints ports. I'm posting the .config file. I had created a selfsigned SSL cert , but i dont know if its correctly bind to the ports. How can i check that?
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
            <section name="TEST" type="System.Configuration.SingleTagSectionHandler"/>         
    </configSections>   
   <system.serviceModel>
    <diagnostics performanceCounters="Default">
     <messageLogging logEntireMessage="false" logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true" />
     <endToEndTracing activityTracing="true" />
    </diagnostics>
    <bindings>
     <basicHttpBinding>
      <binding name="default" maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" maxBufferSize="2147483647"
       maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
          </security>
       <readerQuotas maxDepth="2147483647" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
        maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
      </binding>
     </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
     <service behaviorConfiguration="extern" name="Eps.EDN.Extern">
      <endpoint address="https://127.0.0.1:6080" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="default" name="EpExtern" bindingNamespace="https://csatest.com.ar/Extern"
       contract="Test.EDN.IExtern" />
     </service>
     <service behaviorConfiguration="default" name="Eps.EDN.EpsInternal">
      <endpoint address="https://127.0.0.1:6090" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="default" name="EpCommon" bindingNamespace="https://csatest.com.ar/EpsInternal"
       contract="Test.EDN.ICommon" />
      <endpoint address="https://127.0.0.1:6091" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="default" name="EpUserManagement" bindingNamespace="https://csatest.com.ar/EpsInternal"
       contract="Test.EDN.IUserManagement" />
      <endpoint address="https://127.0.0.1:6092" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="default" name="EpConfiguration" bindingNamespace="https://csatest.com.ar/EpsInternal"
       contract="Test.EDN.IConfiguration" />
      <endpoint address="https://127.0.0.1:6093" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="default" name="EpMeterManagement" bindingNamespace="https://csatest.com.ar/EpsInternal"
       contract="Test.EDN.IMeterManagement" />
      <endpoint address="https://127.0.0.1:6094" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="default" name="EpCustomerManagement" bindingNamespace="https://csatest.com.ar/EpsInternal"
       contract="Test.EDN.ICustomerManagement" />
      <endpoint address="https://127.0.0.1:6095" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="default" name="EpVending" bindingNamespace="https://csatest.com.ar/EpsInternal"
       contract="Test.EDN.IVending" />
     </service>
     <service behaviorConfiguration="report" name="Test.EDN.Reporting.ReportEngine">
      <endpoint address="https://127.0.0.1:6096" binding="basicHttpBinding"
       bindingConfiguration="default" name="EpReportEngine" bindingNamespace="https://csatest.com.ar/ReportEngine"
       contract="Test.EDN.Reporting.IReportEngine" />
     </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="default">
     <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"
      httpsGetUrl="https://127.0.0.1:6100" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="report">
     <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"
      httpsGetUrl="https://127.0.0.1:6101" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
    <behavior name="extern">
     <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true"
      httpsGetUrl="https://127.0.0.1:6102" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="TEST" connectionString="Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(FAILOVER_MODE=(TYPE=select)(METHOD=basic))(SERVER=dedicated)(SERVICE_NAME=XE)));Pooling=True;Connection Timeout=60;Min Pool Size=10;"></add>
  </connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="MaxRecs" value="30"> </add>
    <add key="00" value="TestService.EDN.DLL,Eps.EDN.EpsInternal"> </add>
    <add key="01" value="TestService.EDN.ReportEngine.DLL,Eps.EDN.Reporting.ReportEngine"> </add>
    <add key="02" value="TestService.EDN.External.DLL,Eps.EDN.Extern"> </add>
  </appSettings> 
    <TEST key="2FDB0B5D15CF7076576E0F1B2DB1D986" ID="1"/>
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8"/></startup></configuration>
´´


Based on your configuration code, I suggest the following:
1.You mentioned that you need to do certificate authentication, but in your code:
<security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
</security>

I don't think this will enable certificate authentication, you need to modify the code like I did:
<security mode="Transport">
             <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
  </security>

In the meantime, continue to add:
 <clientCredentials>
            <!-- Specify the client certificate -->
            <clientCertificate storeLocation="LocalMachine"
                               storeName="Root"
                               findValue="TestCertificateSubjectName"
                               x509FindType="FindBySubjectName"/>
            </clientCredentials>

Above is a test-based local certificate that I created.
Finally, I also recommend using wshttpbinding. In some cases, using basichttpbinding will result in an error.
